# Unusual syntax for bitfield declaration

Tags: c, gcc

I came across a bitfield syntax which I have never seen before.

```
       struct msg_hdr0{
                        uint8_t a  : 1,
                        b         : 1,
                        e         : 4,
                        f         : 2;                                                                                                                                                                       
               };

     int main(void)
     {
     struct msg_hdr0 hdr;

     bzero((void *)&hdr, sizeof(hdr));
     hdr.b = 1;

     printf("hdr = 0x%X\n", *(uint32_t *)&hdr);

     return 0;
     }
```

This works fine on linux & gcc compiler.
Can anyone suggest where can I find any documentation on this.
Is this a GCC extension ?

The common bitfield syntax is:

```
    struct box_props
   {
 unsigned int opaque       : 1;
 unsigned int fill_color   : 3;
 unsigned int              : 4; // fill to 8 bits
 unsigned int show_border  : 1;
 unsigned int border_color : 3;
 unsigned int border_style : 2;
 unsigned int              : 2; // fill to 16 bits
};
```

Comment: Bitfields are part of standard C, so any good resource about the language should mention them. Not that it is such a [good idea](http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfields.html) to use them, but that's another issue.

Comment: You are basically telling the compiler how many bits are associated with each member in the structure by doing so you are saving memory. You have say `4 * sizeof(int)  = 16 bytes` without bit fields as size of your struct and by using bit fields you have just 8 bytes as the struct size since 8 bytes is what you need for the whole struct (1 + 1 + 4 + 2)

Comment: Do you mean the single line syntax `int a:1, b:2, c:3, ...` versus the more commonly seen multiple line syntax `int a:1; int b:2; int c:3; ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a function you can declare a list of variables in a single statement, or in multiple statements.

```
void myFunction(void)
{
    // Declare several variables (of teh same type) in a single statement
    int a, b, c;
    // Declare some more, each in their own statement
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
```

Similarly, bit fields in structs.

```
struct myStruct
{
    // Declare several bitfields in a single statement
    int a : 1, b : 3, c : 4;
    // Declare some more, each in their own statement
    int x : 1;
    int y : 3;
    int z : 4;
}
```

Comment: There's no bad at all.  It's a good question.  You could edit the title a little though, now that you've done the 'why didn't I spot that?' routine.  :-)  (E.g. "Unusual syntax for bitfield declaration".)

Answer (score 0):

Standard `C99` section $6.7.2.1 says as,

```
struct-declarator-list:
     struct-declarator
     struct-declarator-list , struct-declarator

struct-declarator:
     declarator
     declarator_opt : constant-expression
```

You can declare struct bit field members using `,` as,

```
   struct msg_hdr0 {
     uint8_t a : 1, b : 1, e : 4, f : 2;
   };
```

Comment: See the common bitfield syntax above, I just want to know from where did the new syntax came from. Is it part of some new C standard, or perhaps GCC extension.

Comment: @Subhasish Its a C standard. Please look at `C99` $6.7.2.1 ISO/IEC 9899:TC3.

Answer (score 0):

For your question how bit fields are used the below code might help. Bit fields are standard in C and are used when the whole size of the int is not required to store the value and a specific number of bits are enough to hold the value by doing so they save memory as shown below. There is already a link in the another answer as to why not use bit fields but for understanding the purpose is this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct a
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
};
struct b
{
    unsigned int a : 2; /* unsigned int a:2, */
                        /*              b:3;  */
    unsigned int b : 3;
};
int main(void) {
    struct b p;
    p.a = 3; /* This member can hold just 2 bits */
    p.b = 7;/* This member can hold just 3 bits */
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct a)); /* Size of struct is 8 bytes */
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct b)); /* size of struct is 4 bytes using bit fields*/
    printf("%d\n",p.a);
    printf("%d\n",p.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see the `struct msg_hdr0` and `struct box_props`. Syntactically both are different. In `struct msg_hdr0`, I do not put uint8_t for each variable and also use a comma to seperate each variable. Is this syntax correct.

Comment: @Subhasish Please note the comma operator here it is similar to `int a,b,c;` it can also be written as `int a:2, b:3;`